# Reading input from remote control device on macs

Tags: python, macos

How could I read input from a remote control device on a mac (iMac, Mac Mini, etc.) and handle actions based on differently pressed buttons in python?

I would like to map the button-press events to my custom app instead of "Front Row". What actions should I take to do that and what python libraries to use to handle the events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Remote Control Wrapper 2](http://www.martinkahr.com/2007/07/26/remote-control-wrapper-20/) library is an Objective C class to handle interaction with Apple Remote Control (and, I believe, also some other such "remote-control-like" devices).  To use some Objective C code from Python, see [pyobjc](http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/).